# How to extract the string numbers from a CSV file and put it in an int array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, io

how to do extract a string number from a csv file and put it in an int array. I tried to do the following but I am not getting what I need. The csv file contains the name and grade separated by comma. In the code below when I print values I get the numbers but as soon as I try to put them in the int array I get a really weird output. 
CSV file content:

```
Betty Mason, 53
Lillian Black,3
Steven Gonzalez , 27
Dorothy Sullivan,80
Bobby Cooper, 68
```

Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Grade {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File("grades.csv"));

    int numberofLines = 0;
    while (s1.hasNext()) {
        String line = s1.nextLine();
        numberofLines++;
    }

    int[] myArray = new int[numberofLines];

    Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File("grades.csv"));
    while (s2.hasNext()) {
        String line = s2.nextLine();
        String[] values = line.split(",");
        String tempValues = values[1].trim();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofLines; i++) {
            myArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempValues);
        }

        System.out.println(myArray);

    }

}
```

}

When I do System.out.println(tempValues); I get

```
53
3
27
80
68
```

And When I do System.out.println(myArray); I get

```
I@3d4eac69
[I@3d4eac69
[I@3d4eac69
[I@3d4eac69
[I@3d4eac69
```

How do I fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To print the content of the array and not its address, use [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

Comment: It gave me an error saying: `cannot find symbol` symbol:   variable Arrays location: class Grade

Comment: Nevermind I did this and it showed up import java.util.Arrays